# Merging mp3 files FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

I need to merge 2 mp3 files (end to end, not mixing them together). The files are located in my res/raw folder. They work when I'm playing them with Media Player, but when I try to merge them, I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream@65561058: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I've been doing trial and error for hours. I figured that I must be providing FileInputStream with the wrong format or something, but it seems like the problem is somewhere else, involving not finding the file or not allowing access to the directory or something. I do realize there are many questions on this website similar to this, but I've looked at countless ones and still did not find a solution.

Here is the code:

```
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {

          File first =  new File(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file101).toString());
          File second = new File(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file103).toString());

          String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
          File file = new File(filepath, "myapp");
          mergeSongs(new File(file.getAbsoluteFile()+"/mergedFile.mp3"), new File[] {first, second});

      }
  },2000);


private void mergeSongs(File mergedFile,File...mp3Files){

    try {
        FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(mp3Files[0]); //Error is at this line
        FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(mp3Files[1]);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mp3Files[0].toString()+mp3Files[1].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(fis1,fis2);

        if(!mergedFile.exists()){
            mergedFile.createNewFile();}

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mergedFile);

        int temp;

         while ((temp = sis.read())!= -1){

                fos.write((byte)temp);

            }

         fis1.close();
         fis2.close();
         sis.close();
         fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

**NEW ERROR:**

```
11-11 11:46:14.180: W/System.err(23975): java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-11 11:46:14.180: W/System.err(23975):    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:946)
11-11 11:46:14.180: W/System.err(23975):    at com.myapp.MainActivity.mergeSongs(MainActivity.java:311)
11-11 11:46:14.180: W/System.err(23975):    at com.myapp.MainActivity.access$7(MainActivity.java:300)
11-11 11:46:14.180: W/System.err(23975):    at com.myapp.MainActivity$8.run(MainActivity.java:290)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your FileInputStreams to InputStreams,and get them like this:

InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file101);

```
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {

          InputStream first =  getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file101);
          InputStream second = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file103);

          String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
          File file = new File(filepath, "myapp");
          mergeSongs(new File(file.getAbsoluteFile()+"/mergedFile.mp3"), new InputStream[] {first, second});

      }
  },2000);


private void mergeSongs(File mergedFile,InputStream...mp3InputStream){

    try {
        InputStream fis1 = mp3InputStream[0]; //Error is at this line
        InputStream fis2 = mp3InputStream[1];
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(fis1,fis2);

        if(!mergedFile.exists()){
            mergedFile.createNewFile();}

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mergedFile);

        int temp;

         while ((temp = sis.read())!= -1){

                fos.write((byte)temp);

            }

         fis1.close();
         fis2.close();
         sis.close();
         fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

**NEW ERROR:**

```
11-11 11:46:14.180: W/System.err(23975): java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-11 11:46:14.180: W/System.err(23975):    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:946)
11-11 11:46:14.180: W/System.err(23975):    at com.myapp.MainActivity.mergeSongs(MainActivity.java:311)
11-11 11:46:14.180: W/System.err(23975):    at com.myapp.MainActivity.access$7(MainActivity.java:300)
11-11 11:46:14.180: W/System.err(23975):    at com.myapp.MainActivity$8.run(MainActivity.java:290)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! With this new code, I get the same error but at a different place. Now I get the error at the mergedFile.createNewFile() line. Any ideas?

Comment: post the exception, please

Comment: Actually, I tried this -  Log.d("mergedFile", mergedFile.toString()); and it shows /storage/emulated/0/myapp/mergedFile.mp3

Comment: use this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29 to create the file